remove zero data at the end of a string
I would like to remove the 0x00 at the end of a string with python3. I try to use rstrip() but it not work.
x = bytearray([0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x00,0x00])
y = x.decode()
z = y.rstrip()
print(z)

How can I get output of z value as 123 .

The issue is because rstrip() removes whitespace by default. To specifically remove 0x00 bytes, you need to pass \x00 to rstrip().

x = bytearray([0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x00, 0x00])
y = x.decode('utf-8')
z = y.rstrip('\x00')
print(z)



'\0' works just as well as '\x00'.

Use str.strip with can takes multiple chars to remove, give it 0 (leading) and \x00 (trailing) .
>>> bytearray([0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x00, 0x00]).decode().strip("0\x00")
123

You can also separate in multiple calls, and use rstrip and lstrip to specify which way to strip .
>>> bytearray([0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x00, 0x00]).decode().rstrip("\x00").lstrip("0")


It's probably a bad idea to remove trailing '0', that changes the meaning.

Removing the Null characters from the right hand side of the data using can be done with rstrip. This can be done directly on the bytearray with rstrip(b'\x00)`
It looks like the value you are expecting out is an integer (123) so you can convert the value with the null bytes stripped to a Python int type which will automatically remove leading zeros. So to modify your example, it might look like:
x = bytearray([0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x00, 0x00])
y = x.rstrip(b'\x00')
z = int(y)
print(z)

